# Python 2.x class in 3.x

Tags: python

I need to use a class written in Python 2.x, but get tons of errors in Blender 2.71 Python 3, any ways around this problem?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't one single way to translate your class from Python 2 to Python 3.

You could try using the command-line tool [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) to do the translation, but it's not perfect, so you'll need to verify the results.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a pure python class then you can run it through the 2to3 as @Garreth mentioned, this will give you the python-3 equivalent in pure syntax updates.

If the class has any Blender specific code, such as using the old `Blender module`, this has been replaced with `bpy`.

If you are creating an add-on, you will need to refactor your code to be registrable as a module. The `bl_info`, register() & unregister()

You will also have to take into account the various api changes that have occured,

- animation IPO system replaced with F-Curves
- BMesh & polygon based geometry system.
- Interface code is done though bpy types